# HTML & CSS How to prevent a div from extending greater the height of the window?

Tags: css, html, position, overflow

How can I prevent a div which contains a long list of items from expanding the page height. I want the div to take up the entire screen but no more so that it doesn't push the footer down.

Comment: Do you have code we can look at?

Comment: How do you plan to show the growing content then?

Comment: @Mihir I was going to use the `css` `overflow: scroll;` attribute.

Comment: Ok in that case: check my solution and updated CSS. Also check: http://jsfiddle.net/NBxqx/10/

Answer (score 2):

Set an specific height for the `div` container, and also set `overflow-y` with auto in order to show the scroll bar only when the content of the div is larger than the height set in the `container`. Like this:

```
.container { 
    height: 500px; 
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: I want the div's height to be somewhat dynamic as some browsers are smaller and others are a lot bigger

Comment: Oh! in this case... why not use `position:fixed` in your footer, and set `bottom:0` on it so it will be always show.

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript/jQuery for this:

**jQuery Solution:**

```
<div id="content-div">some content here</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var height = $(document).height();
  height = height - (your footer height);
  $("#content-div").css({ 'max-height' : height.toString() });
});
```

**Standard JavaScript solution:**

```
<div id="content-div">some content here</div>

 function myfunction () {
       document.getElementById('content-div').style.height = getDocHeight() + 'px';
 }

window.onload = myfunction();

document.getElementById('content-div').style.height = getDocHeight() + 'px';

function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
```

Also, change CSS to:

```
#content-div { background-color:#1d1d1d; color:#eee; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Comment: @Mike: take a look at mine solution

Comment: @DonCallisto - How do you take care of dynamic heights? All machines have different resolutions and window size.

Comment: @Mike - if you need it to be dynamic and cross browser compatible, you will need JavaScript.

Comment: @DonCallisto - % will not solve Mike's problem as % will always give him doc-height relative value and not the exact visible doc-height.

Comment: @Mihir, I am using the http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/ layout template. Will setting the div's positioning to relative mess with the layout so far?

Comment: @Mike - you can delete relative position. It's not necessary for this to work. I have removed it from the above code to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Mihir, where do I call the function and how do I target the div?

Comment: @Mihir, I am not using jQuery so just your standard javascript will do the trick

Comment: Yes use standard JavaScript - check standard JS solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/NBxqx/16/

Comment: Do I wrap the `document.getElementById('displayInbox').style.height = getDocHeight() + 'px';` in a function. And if so, where/when would I call it?

Comment: @Mike: Just wrap it inside <script></script> tag and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Mihir, that doesn't work as the `getDocHeight` function isn't even called. Do I need to call the function onWindowResize, onload etc?

Comment: @Mike - Yes, you put it inside a function and call the function like this: window.onload = myfunction(); check my updated JavaScript solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22772/discussion-between-mihir-and-mike)

Answer (score -1):

Without js, it is not possible because your page can be viewed in different resolution. Different resolutions means different height. Matter of fact, you may want that behaviour when user resizes the browser window as well, am I right? So first, find out the height of the browser, subtract the height of the footer from it, and set this height to your container, which I believe you want to make scroll able on yaxis. That will solve the problem. All these tasks are pretty simple and you can do it by little googling.

Comment: Are you suggesting something similar (if not the same) to @Mihir's solution?

Comment: Yes. If your footer has a dynamic height, you can use the same technique to find out its height as well. Matter of fact I suggest using the same technique to find footer height as well.